# Python automatically converting data types

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-conversion

I have implemented a class `BasicForm`, containing also a method `__str__` to be able to print stuff. I also have a function `stringToBasicForm(string)` converting certain types of strings to BasicForm objects.

Later in my program, I have an array `array` of allowed strings, and I do the following:

```
for i in xrange(len(array)):
    array[i] = stringToBasicForm(array[i])
```

My problem is that, after this, `array` appears to contain objects of type `str` and not of type `BasicForm` as I would have expected. I think that Python is automatically converting my BasicForms to strings using `__str__` for some reason.

What is happening? How can I make it so that my array contains the good type of objects at the end (without creating an auxiliary array)?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Remark:** I'm using Python 2.7

---

Here's a small-ish working example:

```
from fractions import *
from numpy import *

class BasicForm:

    def __init__(self,n,coeff,I):

        if shape(I)[1] != n + 1:
            print "Error: illegal I."
            return
        if not all([isinstance(f,Fraction) for f in coeff]):
            print "Error: coefficients must be of class Fraction."
            return

        self.n = n

        vect = zeros(2**(n+1)-1,dtype = Fraction)
        for i in xrange(len(I)):
            if not any(I[i]):
                print "Error: the empty set doesn't code any basic form."
                return
        vect[subsetToIndex(n,I[i])] = coeff[i]
        self.vect = vect

    def __str__(self):

        if not any(self.vect):
            return "0"

        s = ""
        first = True
        for i in xrange(2**(self.n+1)-1):
            if self.vect[i] == 0:
                continue
            if self.vect[i] < 0:
                s += "-"
                if not first:
                    s = s[:-3] + "- "
            if self.vect[i] != 1:
                s += str(abs(self.vect[i])) + "*"
            s += "("
            I = indexToSubset(self.n,i)
            for k in xrange(self.n+1):
                if I[k]:
                    s += str(k)
            s += ") + "
            first = False

        return s[:-2]

def stringToBasicForm(n,string):

    out = BasicForm(n,[Fraction(0)],[ones(n+1,dtype = bool)])

    return out
```

Now for the weird part. If I run this with

```
n = 1
array = ["(01)"]
for i in xrange(len(array)):
    array[i] = stringToBasicForm(n,array[i])
    print isinstance(array[i],BasicForm), isinstance(array[i],str)
```

everything works as expected (output: `True False`). But if I run it with

```
def opPBT(n,LPBT,BF_array):

    tree = copy(LPBT)
    array = copy(BF_array)

    # Convert basic forms to elements to the Sullivan algebra (injection).
    for i in xrange(len(array)):
        if isinstance(array[i],str):
            array[i] = stringToBasicForm(n,array[i])
            print isinstance(array[i],BasicForm), isinstance(array[i],str)
        elif array[i].n != n:
            print "Error: basic form of wrong dimension."
            return
        array[i] = basicToSullivan(array[i])
    return

n = 2
forms = ["(01)"]
lcomb = []
opPBT(n,lcomb,forms)
```

which is what I would like to do, then the output is `False True`, and I have absolutely no clue of what I'm doing wrong (it's probably some stupid error but I'll be damned if I can see it...)

Comment: What does `stringToBasicForm` do?

Comment: No, Python would never do that conversion by itself with a for loop like that. We'd like a look at your stringToBasicForm function.

Comment: @timakro It converts certain strings to 'BasicForm's. It works without problems and returns the correct data type.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Ok, I've posted the code.

Comment: As @RemcoGerlich said, if `stringToBasicForm` returns objects of type `BasicForm` the list will be filled with those, python does no conversion by itself.

Comment: *"`array` appears to contain objects of type `str` and not of type `BasicForm`"* - on what basis? What is `BasicForm`'s `__repr__`esentation? Could you give a [mcve]? That's quite a long and complex function most of which seems irrelevant.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've checked using `isinstance(array[i],BasicForm)` and `isinstance(array[i],str)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I will try to give a self-contained example. I haven't defined a `__repr__` function for `BasicForm`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added an example. Probably I could reduce the code further, but anyway I'm pretty sure that the error is located in the last snippet of code.

Comment: The example is still not Minimal, Complete, *or* Verifiable. There are missing imports and functions.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Sorry, there was a `from numpy import *`missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy arrays are *strongly typed*:

```
>>> x = np.empty((3,), dtype=np.float64)
>>> x[0] = 1  # I put an int in...
>>> x[0]      # And get a float out !
1.0
```

Usually, the array will try to convert values you pass in (which is typically what you want, cf the example above, where you wouldn't want the whole thing to crash because you forgot a `.` after the `1`). Since you have a convenient `__str__`, it will use that to ensure that your array is consistent.

What does that have to do with your problem ? I suspect the `copy` you're using is the numpy copy:

```
>>> from numpy import copy
>>> copy([1,2,3]) # List in, array out...
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Which would explain your automatic coercion; normal Python lists do not operate like that:

```
>>> foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> class A(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "converted !"
...
>>> bar = copy(foo)
>>> bar[0] = A()
>>> foo[0] = A()
>>> type(foo[0])
__main__.A
>>> type(bar[0])
numpy.string_
>>> isinstance(bar[0], str)
True
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks you, I would never have found out by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your stringToBasicForm function the return value must be None or a BasicForm instance ...

Can you just check with type() ?

```
class BasicForm:
def __init__(self, s):
    pass

def __str__(self):
    return "PLOP"

array = ['toto', 'tata', 'tutu']

print([type(elem) for elem in array])

for i, elem in enumerate(array):
    array[i] = BasicForm(elem)

print([type(elem) for elem in array])
```

output:

```
[<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]
[<class '__main__.BasicForm'>, <class '__main__.BasicForm'>, <class '__main__.BasicForm'>]
```

Comment: Yes, in my example above the output is `[<type 'instance'>]` for the first version, and `[<type 'numpy.string_'>]`for the second one.